# Can the 3D viewport be set to draw smooth (anti-aliased) wireframe?

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

When I create mesh etc the wireframe looks so jagged. Coming from other applications I've used, most of them seem to have smooth wireframe (Maya to name one).

Are smooth wireframes possible in Blender?

I'm using a MacPro and my version is 2.71.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about anti-aliasing:

[image: AA]

This can be turned on in the User Preferences (found in the File menu), in the System tab:

[image: screenshot AA]

You may need to click **Save User Settings** at the bottom left and restart Blender to see any effect.

---

Warning, on some systems (NVidia specifically) this can cause editmode vert/edge/face selection to fail. (This is an issue with the OpenGL driver and not much Blender can do to resolve)

Comment: Doesn't do anything for me... Using the blender snap (2.79) on ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @Tooniis did you "save user settings" and restarted Blender?

Comment: @Winand yes I did

Comment: It works now on Ubuntu 18.04